# Before Uploading check basename and filename

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-comparison

How do i check the directory name and string name are equal before uploading the data into AWS S3 bucket.When i uploaded data into s3 i get error invalid data.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
            'version'     => 'latest',
            'region'      => 'ap-south-1',
            'credentials' => [
                'key'        => 'xxxxx',
                'secret'     => 'yyyyy',
            ],
        ]);
    $bucket = "naveen";
    $ACL    = "public-read";
    $path                = "/Naveen-Backup/project-requirements/admin";
    $file                = basename($path);
    $BundleFolderName = "admin";
    $BundleFile       = $_FILES['Bundle']['name'];
    $BundlePathToFile = $_FILES['Bundle']['tmp_name'];
    $BundleKey        = "Bundles/test/${BundleFolderName}/".$BundleFile;
if ($file == $BundleFolderName) {
    $admin = 'http://'.$bucket.'.s3.amazonaws.com/'.$BundleKey;
    $s3->putObject([
            'Bucket'     => $bucket,
            'Key'        => $BundleKey,
            'ACL'        => $ACL,
            'SourceFile' => $iosBundlePathToFile
        ]);
}
$query = new mysqli(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
$mydb = "INSERT INTO `admin`( `admin`)  VALUES ('$admin')";
if (mysqli_query($query, $mydb)){
    echo "upload success";
} else{
    echo ("Error description: ".mysqli_error($query));
}
}
```

Comment: var_dump($file); var_dump($BundleFolderName); Check whether the DataType of 2 strings are same. If not then you must typecast and use === for strict comparison.

Comment: i get an error invalid character admin